# Send a XML using php soap

Tags: php, xml, soap, send

i'm new on SOAP operations.
I already get access to a few available services on the server. But there's one that a can't access.

A need do send the following XML:

```
     <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"   xmlns:ser="http://www.cnj.jus.br/servico-intercomunicacao-2.2.2/" xmlns:tip="http://www.cnj.jus.br/tipos-servico-intercomunicacao-2.2.2" xmlns:int="http://www.cnj.jus.br/intercomunicacao-2.2.2">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <ser:entregarManifestacaoProcessual>
         <tip:idManifestante>xxxxxx</tip:idManifestante>
         <tip:senhaManifestante>Exxxxxx</tip:senhaManifestante>
         <tip:numeroProcesso>50000010820198210022</tip:numeroProcesso>
         <tip:documento  tipoDocumento="348" mimetype="application/pdf" descricao="DESCRICAO DA PETICAO" >
         </tip:documento>
         <tip:dataEnvio>20231009204853</tip:dataEnvio>
      </ser:entregarManifestacaoProcessual>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>'
```

I tried the following code:

```
 $client       = new SoapClient("https://eproc1g-ws.tjrs.jus.br/eproc/wsdl.php?    srv=intercomunicacao2.2", array('trace' => 1));
    $params = array(
            "idManifestante" => "xxxxxx",
            "senhaManifestante" => ""xxxxxx,
            "numeroProcesso" => "50000010820198210022",
            "dataEnvio" => "20231009204853",  
            "documento" => "",
        "tipoDocumento" => "348",
        "mimetype" => "application/pdf",
        "descricao" => "DESCRICAO DA PETICAO"
    );
$response = $client->__soapCall("entregarManifestacaoProcessual", array($params));
```

But i realize that the array structure is wrong.

How can i organize the $params var to generate the correct XML ?

Comment: You need to structure the array to nested elements in your XML template

Comment: $params = array(
    "entregarManifestacaoProcessual" => array(
        "idManifestante" => "xxxxxx",

Comment: also in documento

"documento" => array(
            "tipoDocumento" => "348",
            "mimetype" => "application/pdf",
            "descricao" => "DESCRICAO DA PETICAO"
        ),